# MySQL - how to use index in WHERE x IN (<subquery>)

Tags: mysql, indexing, subquery

I'm using this query to get all employees of {clients with name starting with lowercase "a"}:

```
SELECT * FROM employees 
  WHERE client_id IN (SELECT id FROM clients WHERE name LIKE 'a%')
```

Column `employees.client_id` is an int, with `INDEX client_id (index_id)`. The subquery should IMHO return a list of id-s, which is then used in the WHERE clause.

When I `EXPLAIN` the query, the primary query uses no indexes (`type:ALL`). But when I `EXPLAIN`
 a list taken from the subquery (e.g. `SELECT ... WHERE client_id IN (121,184,501)`), the `EXPLAIN` switches to `type:range`, and this query gets faster by 50%.

How can I make the query use the index for the data returned by subquery - or, is there a more efficient way of retrieving this data? (Retrieving the id-list to application server, joining it and sending a second query is even more expensive here).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT employees.*
FROM   employees, clients
WHERE  employees.client_id = clients.id
AND    clients.name LIKE 'a%';
```

Should be more quicker, since the optimiser can choose the most efficient plan.  In writing it your way with a sub-query, you're forcing it to do the steps in a certain order rather than letting it choose the optimal join order.

As a general rule sub-queries should be avoided since they will typically be less performant than a join query (though there are certain circumstances where they are unavoidable)

Comment: Could also use INNER JOIN syntax.

Comment: I have seen cases where the query optimiser gets it really wrong, and a subquery to return ID's was loads faster. But it was a really specific case.

See: http://www.benlumley.co.uk/2008/06/25/mysql-query-optimiser-left-lacking/ if you are interested in details.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to do this with a `JOIN` and not a subselecct ?

```
SELECT employees.* FROM employees, clients WHERE employees.client_id = clients.id  AND clients.name LIKE 'a%';
```

Answer (score 4):

For a specific explanation on why

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE client_id IN (SELECT id FROM clients WHERE name LIKE 'a%')
```

is slower than

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE client_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Check out this part of the MySQL manual, particuarly the third dot point: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html. Also, this [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9090).

Answer (score 2):

It is worth pointing out that joins performing better than subqueries does not hold true for every DBMS there is. It sure does for MySQL though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.*  
FROM employees e  
WHERE EXISTS (   
  SELECT 1    
  FROM clients c  
  WHERE c.id = e.client_id   
  AND c.name LIKE 'a%'
)
```

You can rewrite the query using **EXISTS**. In MySQL, it definitely gives a performance improvement. For more optimization help, you could refer : [MySQL-In-Query-Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/in-subquery-optimization.html)

Comment: I don't think using any kind of subquery is an improvement with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from X as _x where 
  exists(select * from Y as _y where _y.someField = _x.someField)
```

Should do the trick for you ;)